# Use shell to load in variables to replace placeholders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I have a problem where my config files contents are placed within my deployment script because they get their settings from my setting.sh file. This causes my deployment script to be very large a bloated.

I was wondering if it would be possible in bash to do something like this

**setting.sh**

```
USER="Tom"
```

**log.conf**

```
log=/$PLACEHOLDER_USER/full.log
```

**deployment.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pull in settings file
. ./settings.sh

# Link config to right location
ln -s /home/log.conf /home/logging/log.conf

# Write variables on top of placeholder variables in the file
for $PLACEHOLDER_* in /home/logging/log.conf
do
(Replace $PLACEHOLDER_<VARAIBLE> with $VARIABLE)
done
```

I want this to work for any variable found in the config file which starts with $placeholder_

This process would allow me to move a generic config file from my repository and then add the proper variables from my setting file on top of the placeholder variables in the config.

I'm stuck on how I can get this to actually work using my deployment.sh.

Comment: How about just `source`ing your config files (the ones which define `USER=Tom` etc.) and then simply use `"$USER"`?

Comment: It seems like programs like supervisor don't allow sourcing of external files

Comment: Whoa?  How should they be able to prevent that?  If there's a file besides my current script then I can source it using `source filename`.  How should supervisor inhibit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small script will read all variable lines from `settings.sh` and replace the `PLACEHOLDER_xxx` in `file` for each.  Does this help you?

```
while IFS== read variable value
do
  sed -i "s/\$PLACEHOLDER_$variable/$value/g" file
done < settings.sh
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for that. That seems good but approaches it from a different direction that I was thinking. Is it not better to read all variables PLACEHOLDER_XXX and replace with the value of $XXX?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/env bash
set -x

ln -s /home/log.conf /home/logging/log.conf

while read user
do
usertmp=$(echo "${user}" | sed s'@USER=\"@@' \
sed s'@"$@@')
user="${usertemp}"
log="${user}"/full.log
done < setting.sh
```

I don't really understand the rest of what you're trying to do, I will confess, but this will hopefully give you the idea.  Use read.

Comment: I don;t think this is quite what I am after. I looking to find any variables in the file like this $PLACEHOLDER_<VARIABLE> and replace with the value of $VARIABLE in the settings.sh. For example if the file has "$PLACEHOLDER_USER" it will put "Tom" in that file